# What happens, if a liquid/gas is kept on constant high pressure in a closed container for a long period?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, superfluidity

On applying non-increasing constant pressure,
I need to understand the case for liquid and gas.

If container is not inescapable:

1. Will the liquid/gas heat up?
2. Will any of their properties change?

How I can measure the pressure?

Can you help in finding the best book, so that I can go through to understand these concepts?

Comment: Gas / liquid is stored in gas tanks with no issues : propane, butane etc What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify rate of heat gain/loss (or a way to calculate it due to container properties and internal & external temperatures).  You can maintain constant pressure by using a cylindrical container with a weighted piston lid: the pressure will just depend on the area and weight of the lid.  No need to measure the pressure.

If heat is continually lost, the gas will gradually convert to liquid.  If heat is continually gained, the liquid will gradually convert to gas.  Any good book on thermodynamics should give you the background to understand the process.